# diskCacheStrategy Not working in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-glide

[image]

```
[ @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final ChatUser user = list.get(i);
    viewHolder.title.setText(user.getName());
    Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + user.getName() + "-" + user.getImageurl());
    if (user.getImageurl().isEmpty() || user.getImageurl().equals("")) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_profile_picture).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile_blue).into(viewHolder.profile_image);
    } else {
        Glide.with(context).load(user.getImageurl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(viewHolder.profile_image);
    }
}]
```

`diskCacheStrategy` has set to `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` still it is not working for me.
Anyone can help please do.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you know that it is not working?

Comment: Does not working means it's not caching or you're not getting an image?

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).